# Replace fragment caused RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()’ on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, null, leanback

I am using the android tv leanback sample here,
https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback

when I try to replace fragment in `MainFragment` like this

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_frame, SampleFragment)
.addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

it crash with

> android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()’ on a
>   null object reference
>       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.findMinMaxChildLayoutPositions(RecyclerView.java:3989)

and it happens even I replace with a blank fragment

Comment: please share your code for fragment transaction

Comment: You obviously have some odd behavior with your RecyclerView adapter

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following pattern and it should help you resolve the issue. I had the same exact issue and took me awhile to figure it out finally.

```
 FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, destinationFragment, null);
            ft.commit();
```

Note: No need to add ".addToBackStack(null)"